# iCarousel ZOOM(pinch)

Tags: iphone, ios, pinchzoom, icarousel

I would like to add zooming capabilities to the **currentItemView** . I've tried to create a scrollview and add it as a subview of the view from the datasource method. But had no luck doing it.

If anybody has an example and is willing to share it please do so. Or at least some proper steps in order to succeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an GestureRecognizer to the View.
2. First of All Add an UIImageView to the View which is of same size as the Icarousel images.
3. Then Add that UIImageView into the ScrollView now you can ZOOM the UIImageView you have created.
4. AfterWards add the respective code in Icarousel DidBegin Scroll method to hide the UIImageView.
   Since I'm not having that much time, but i have an example for you in GitHub for showing an example of Presenting an Animation with Icarousel, you can find it [Here :)](https://github.com/prabhuNatarajan/Icarousel-Zooming)